# Age not calculating correctly PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
ID INT(3) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Age INT(3) NOT NULL,
Date DATE
);
```

Date stores date of birth from user.I have to calculate age from the date of birth.I first just input the DOB and name to DB.
I now retrieve the last auto-increment through:

```
$last=mysqli_insert_id($sqli);
echo "$last";
```

I now retrieve the year part from DOB:

```
$sql="SELECT YEAR(Date) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID='$last'";
$sql2=$sqli->query($sql);
if($sql2)
{
   echo "date retrieved";
   $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
   $rdate=$row['YEAR(Date)'];     // Year part DOB stored
   echo "$rdate";
}
```

I fetch the current date by:

```
$cdate;   //current date
$sql='SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())';
$sql2=$sqli->query($sql);
if($sql2)
{
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
 $cdate=$row['YEAR(CURDATE())'];
 echo "$cdate";
}
```

I now calculate the age by :

```
 $diff=abs(strtotime($cdate)-strtotime($rdate));
 echo "<br/> before divide : ";
 echo "$diff";
 $diff=floor($diff/(24*60*60*365)); //convert to years
```

Lastly I update the table with the value of age:

```
 $sql="UPDATE EMPLOYEE
     SET Age='$diff' WHERE ID='$last'";
```

Now the problem is that when I try to enter a DOB like from 2010+ or something the age shown is 0.The program calculates for ages from <2000 perfectly.I also have a output to show my problem:

```
 name is pit
 successfulvalue inserted56date retrieved20122018   
 before divide : 360
 age after 1st divide:0age updated
```

Here DOB is 2012
Please help me in finding the solution.I am new to PHP and need some help.

Comment: You should take a good look at your logic: You have the complete date of birth stored in your database yet you only retrieve the year. There is no way you can reliably calculate someone's age using just the year. It takes two dates.

Comment: Why you going to complicated it's simple just get the full date of that user dob then calculate from current date. And one more thing why you use echo "$last" this for PHP variable echo.

Comment: +rowmoin that's exactly what I am doing.I need the year part to find the age.Please go through my code once.I have tried to explain wherever I felt the need for it...I am getting age as 0.

Comment: Imagine it's the 1st of July. If you had your birthday in January you'd be 1 year older than if you had your birthday in December the same year. Obviously the year is not enough.

Comment: +h2ooooooo Can you help me with working code please.I am new and could not find help by google.

Comment: [The MySQL manual has the SQL you need](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-calculations.html). `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Date, CURDATE())`

Comment: Thanks.This solved my problem..and its better too!!

Comment: I wouldnt store the age in the database, because it’s only correct right when you update it (next time you read the age column it could be wrong).  Rather, calculate the age when you are about to display or use it, from the current date and the date of birth.